# Run Python after ssh is closed

Tags: python, pi-3

I want to run a python script that goes on infinitely, but it stops after I have closed the ssh terminal. I would also like to see the output from the script when I log in again.

Comment: You can use tmux to create a session that will continue to run even after you disconnect and can reattach later even from a different computer. As for the length of the output have you considered writing it to a combination of logfile and regular files.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to solve this. You could setup your Python script as a service. A pretty good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.diegoacuna.me/how-to-run-a-script-as-a-service-in-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/).

Another option is to have the script simply launch on startup. A good tutorial to follow can be found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/).

As for the output, I would suggest that you create a file and write your output to that file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nohup` command

example:

```
nohup yourCommand &
```

after that you can quit ssh and when you go in again, you can find the file `nohup.out` that contains the output.

take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/nohup-1/index.html)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but when I open nohup.out it doesn't respond- likely because there is a lot of output. Is there any other way around the problem?

Comment: if there is a lot of output, this is the output you have on your python script, you can try to reduce this output if it is useless

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is either `screen` or `tmux` (I prefer the latter). These create a detachable console that you can then leave and then reattach to later.